# Beta/Dirichlet question

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

A generalization of the beta distribution is the Dirichlet distribution. In its bi-variate version, (X,Y) have pdf

$f(x,y) = Cx^{a-1}y^{b-1}(1-x-y)^{c-1}, 0<x<1, 0<y<1, 0<y<1-x<1$,

where $a>0,b>0, c> 0 $ are constants.

(a)Show that $C = \frac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)\Gamma(c)}{\Gamma(a+b+c)}$

(b) Show that, marginally, both X and Y are beta.

(c) Find the conditional distribution of $Y|X=x$ and show that $Y/(1-x)$ is beta(b,c).

(d) Show that $E(XY) =\frac{ab}{(a+b+c+1)(a+b+c)}$, and find their covariance.

Attempt at (a):

$\int_0^1\int_0^{1-x} x^{a-1}y^{b-1}(1-x-y)^{c-1}dx dy$

$\int_0^1x^{a-1}\int_0^{1-x} y^{b-1}(1-x-y)^{c-1}dx dy$

Let $u=\frac{y}{(1-x)}$

$\int_0^1x^{a-1}(1-x)^{b+c-1}dx\int_0^1 u^{b-1}(1-u)^{c-1}du$

$\int_0^1x^{a-1}(1-x)^{b+c-1}dx*\frac{\Gamma(b)\Gamma(c)}{\Gamma(b+c)}$

$\frac{\Gamma(b)\Gamma(c)}{\Gamma(b+c)}\int_0^1x^{a-1}(1-x)^{b+c-1}dx$

$\frac{\Gamma(b)\Gamma(c)}{\Gamma(b+c)}\frac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b+c)}{\Gamma(a+b+c)}$

$\frac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)\Gamma(c)}{\Gamma(a+b+c)}$

Not sure how to correctly do parts b-d

Comment: If you accept a detailed answer 9 minutes after it was posted, it means you have no problem with understanding it right away. Which brings the question of why you had problems with the question itself when you asked it. You say nothing about this, can you expand on this mystery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part (b), you already did it when you did part (a), since the marginal distribution of $X$ is given by $$f_X(x) = \int_{y=0}^{1-x} f_{X,Y}(x,y) \, dy,$$ which you evaluated already.

For part (c), the conditional distribution is given by $$f_{Y\mid X}(y) = \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_X(x)}.$$

For part (d), you would calculate $$\mathrm{E}[XY] = \int_{x=0}^1 \int_{y=0}^{1-x} xy f_{X,Y}(x,y) \, dy \, dx.$$